# Is there a way to resend invitation after creating softlayer ID using API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Sometimes user do not accept invitation within 24hrs and we need to send them again. Is there a way to send it using softlayer API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You need to use the method [SoftLayer_User_Customer::inviteUserToLinkOpenIdConnect](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/inviteUserToLinkOpenIdConnect), the invitation lasts 7 days.

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userID]/inviteUserToLinkOpenIdConnect

Method: POST

{
    "parameters":[
        "IBMid"
    ]
}
```

Change **[userName]**,**[apiKey]** and **[userID]** with your own data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in nodejs and it worked fine.

```
slClient
    .auth(slUserID, slApiKey)
    .path('User_Customer', userID, 'inviteUserToLinkOpenIdConnect')
    .parameters(["IBMid"])
    .post()
    .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
```